# How change the number of the first slide from 1 to 0 in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm creating a powerpoint presentation with excel VBA, and I´m having a problem when trying to change the number of the first slide from 1 to cero.

I can't seem to find a solution or a code for this action anywhere, so I was wondering if everyone around here knew how to do this.

I know it can me made manually with the "Number Slides From" button on Page Setup, but I need to know how to do this with VBA.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in case it is useful for anybody:

```
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation

...

pptPres.PageSetup.FirstSlideNumber = 0
```

:)